# Magento 2 - How to Disable cart only for a specific store view?

Tags: magento2, cart, multistore, store-view

I need to hide/remove cart only for PROFESSIONAL ENGLISH store view.

Store structure on attached image.[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you use For PROFESSIONAL ENGLISH store view for different theme?

Comment: both store views of INDUSTRIAL = themeA
both store views of PROFESSIONAL = themeB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I found solution myself: I have added on HTML in Admin side ,please login in admin go to this path :-  "

> content->design->configuration->(store view)-> footer -> miscellaneous
>   HTML:

```
<style type="text/css" xml="space">
 <!--
    .minicart-wrapper{display: none!important;}
  -->
</style>
```

add the style in miscellaneous HTML